# Is there any way to use "one single template parameter" for several different "std::class types"?

Tags: c++, templates

-Hello everyone, I'm pretty much a beginner.
-Is there anyway that I can merge "the 2 following function templates" into a single one?
, like we can use T3= {  std::list<T || std::forward_list } and then merge these 2 functions into one?
-My heavy gratitude in advance :) .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <forward_list>

template <class T> void prinList(std::list<T> list){
    for (auto var : list){ std::cout << var << " "; }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
template <class T> void prinList(std::forward_list<T> list){
    for (auto var : list){ std::cout << var << " "; }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
int main(){
    std::forward_list<int> F_list1={1,2,3,4,5};
    prinList(F_list1);

    std::list<int> list1={10,11,12,13};
    prinList(list1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can do it the following way:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <forward_list>

template <class T> void prinList(T const & list) {
    for (auto var : list) { std::cout << var << " "; }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::forward_list<int> F_list1 = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    prinList(F_list1);

    std::list<int> list1 = { 10,11,12,13 };
    prinList(list1);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5
10 11 12 13
```

**[Live demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/e69K3PWGc)**

**Notes:**

1. The `list` parameter is accepted by a `const &` to avoid copy and also protect against attempt to modify the list.
2. `list` can be in fact any container or similar class that supports the range-based loop, making the function more generic (you might want to rename it accordingly).

Comment: @Rango that's a little too long for a search of what is basic essence of template. And you actually can combine your version (which is a case of overloaded template functions) and thisgeneric template version. I.e. if you have to separate `T` and `T::data__type` not rely on `T::data__type` being declared.

Comment: Thanks @Swift-FridayPie! Would you mind consider the extra question bellow? (question in the form of answer :D )

Comment: Thank @wohlstad! Would you mind consider the extra question bellow? (question in the form of answer :D )

Comment: @Rango, as mentioned below, please post a new question. This is the way StackOverflow works.

Comment: @wohstad Yeah! thank a lot. I'll do that